# Running the google places modal popup in flutter

Tags: flutter

Looking at the flutter code it seems like I should be able to run the google places modal dialog since it does a full screen thing and doesn't try and overlay on top of flutter.

However I am having an issue where the modal shows up and then disappears again immediately.  I am not entirely sure how to solve this...

I am activating it with:

```
call.method == "openPlacesDialogModal" -> {
val code = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity)
if (GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().showErrorDialogFragment(activity, code, REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES)) {
    return
 }

 //val intent = Intent(activity, PlacesActivity::class.java)
 //activity.startActivity(intent)

 var intentBuilder = PlacePicker.IntentBuilder()
 activity.startActivityForResult(intentBuilder.build(activity), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST)

    placeResult = result
    return
}
```

In the logs I get:

```
I/FlutterActivityDelegate(18184): onResume setting current activity to this
I/flutter (18184): Opening picker
I/FlutterActivityDelegate(18184): onResume setting current activity to this
```

I think it is the `onResume` getting back to the `ActivityDelegate` that is the issue.

I put this on top of a completely different activity too, which kind of works.  It shows the dialog for longer.  I made sure I have all the right permissions, I have the fine location, internet permissions.  Do I need to setup anything else?

Thanks,
David.

Answer (score 0):

Error here was that I was not setting up the google api correctly and it was erroring immediately.  Had to put in some checks to look for this error so I could respond correctly to the app that an error occurred.